# What does "LB" out mean in a DC-DC buck converter?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck, output, input

Teacher gave me a schematic,and it includes a DC/DC buck converter with "LB" input and output,but i have no idea what the "LB" is,so i want to ask that does someone know what may the "LB" be?

[image]

Comment: Neverrrr heard that used before but somewhere there is an inductor L in and out.

Comment: Oddly enuf, mechanical engineers use it to measure "buckling forces" in and out of plane and trump tweets how Buck trades IN to Canada gotta improve in NAFTA  .. (lol)

Comment: Better ask prof to show a datasheet with this on it

Comment: I agree it with you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"LB" stands for "low battery". 
They are the input and output pins for a comparator and voltage reference (internal to the device) which can be wired to detect a low battery voltage and provide a shutdown signal.

For example, see this Linear Technology datasheet, page 4:
http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/126535fb.pdf

"LBOUT (Pin  3): Open-Drain  Output  of  the  Low-Battery
Comparator. This pin will sink current when Pin 4 (LBIN)
goes  below  1.25V.  During  shutdown,  this  pin  is  high
impedance.

LBIN  (Pin 4): The (–) Input of the Low-Battery Comparator.
The (+) input is connected to a reference voltage of 1.25V."

Comment: Thx,i will make sure it with my prof. tomorrow