# Unpredicted behavior in an energy harvester circuit using max666

Tags: mosfet, voltage-regulator, simulation, proteus, energy-harvesting

I conducted the simulation of a circuit used for energy harvesting. Its functioning is explained in detail in [How the voltage stable mechanism work in Bridge rectifier?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/358847/how-the-voltage-stable-mechanism-work-in-bridge-rectifier?rq=1). But it was observed in the simulation that the voltage across energy storing capacitor(C1 in the link above and C4 in the simulation figure) is becoming constant at 5V rather than charging and discharging about 12V as designed using the zener diode. Why is this happening?[image]

Comment: First things first. If you break the circuit at the ammeter reading 15.2uA (should have a name!) so there is no load, what voltage is on C4? If 5V, that's all you get from your energy source.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I don't know whether you checked the link in the question but the circuit was designed in such a way that the capacitor can charge upto 12.6V before the base-emitter starts conducting( due to zener with 12 V). Why is that not happening?

Comment: That is what my question was aimed at finding out.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I check it as you suggested. The voltage across the capacitor is increasing with time till it saturates depending on the value of Vin. It reaches higher values than 5V.

Comment: OK. Is the rate of increase consistent with charging C4 with more than 15.2uA?

Comment: I checked the charging current of C4 without load and it was a half wave rectified sine wave with a peak of 11uA

Comment: And yet your first ammeter shows 15uA. Looks like all that circuitry is draining the current before the capacitor can reach 12V. So, where is it going?

Comment: I checked the simulation and out of the 15uA, 8uA goes to the emitter and the rest to the IC. But the transistor should not be conducting until capacitor reaches 12V . It's confusing.

Comment: You changed the biasing conditions around the transistor (compared to the linked circuit) ... how did you test those changes? could they lead to an increase in current? Also teh other two ammeters read 6 and 3 uA ... meaning the other 3 uA is via R3.

Comment: I checked with the exact same conditions ie R1=501k and R2=1 M and there was not much difference in the behavior except for small changes in the current value due to changes in resistance. And the 3uA flows to the left through Q2 and a current of 8uA flows through R3. I have modified the image in the question with ammeters at critical nodes.

Comment: I can only conclude the original had more than 15uA available. First, boost your source current (e.g. increase C1)  to see if the cct works at some higher current. If so, try scaling ALL the impedances by 5 or 10 to reduce the consumption with your actual source

Comment: @BrianDrummond I increased my input voltage by 3 times the current rose to 45uA still everything else remains the same. C1 is only able to charge till 5V. Can u see any difference between the circuit in the link and the simulation i provided?

Comment: Not that I haven't pointed out. 3uA in Q2 is suspicious. If this wasn't a sim I'd suspect ESD and replace it. But at Vgs=0.7 it's possible it's close to threshold (I haven't looked at its datasheet). And current in R3 would keep Q1 on, I don't follow .... wait ... why are C2 and C3 grounded to the output side? That and Q2 body diode makes a charge pump.